# Add httpheader to a soap service in a .net6 rest application. Soap service is injected in a channelfactory as generic

Tags: .net, http, wcf, soap, https

Anyone have an idea how to pass an http header to a soap service in a .net6 rest api application, which is a generic channel factory that injects the soap service. An http header on the runtime stack is no problem of course. But httpHeader must be passed to the service. And an endpoint behavior does not do the thing. I know this will work in a separate runtime stack/separate proxy, but I want to avoid this by working with a separate proxy only for an id here.

Comment: Can you provide some materials (such as code and pictures) to help us better understand the problem? This is of great help to us in helping you solve your problems.